# Split by bookmark in middle of PDF page

Tags: pdf

For a little open-source project I am trying to split PDFs based on the bookmark information. I found several ways to split them by page, but sadly the PDFs I need to split have bookmarks in the middle of the page. So if I have 3 pages and there are two bookmarks, 1 at the first page, one at the middle of the 2nd page, I need to extract 2 PDFs with 2 pages each and no overlap in text in both PDFs.

Does something like that exist?

Comment: What would you want the PDFs to look like? If you think they would reflow the answer is no. If you think like you cut them with scissors then the answer is possibly (unless you have columns in the PDF). A PDF is not a word processing file type.

Comment: Cutting with scissor is totally okay. I am aware that PDFs are basically free floating boxes of content.